# Which is correct here? Came vs Come

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, tenses

This seems like a simple question but I'm stuck.  I'm writing about Millennials and want to reference their background.  Which is correct (and why)?  Below is the sentence and (because it may be relevant to the answer) it's lead in:

**To understand what Millennials want, let’s look at how they are different from us – including how their up-bringing differed from that of prior generations.  More Millenials came (or come?) from families where both parents were actively involved in their up-bringing.**

Comment: Upbringing (no hyphen) and previous (not prior). But this is really an ELL question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use *come*. You are saying that more millennials come from families where both parents were actively involved. Using *came* would imply that they don't anymore. You'd be talking about them as if they no longer existed.

I would also change 'were' to *are*.

So the final sentence reads, 'More Millennials come from families where both parents are actively involved in their up-bringing.'

There is probably a real answer to this, but this sounds right, in my opinion.